# get first and last element from List<DTO>

Tags: java, foreach

I am iterating a `List<MyDTO>` to get the results. My requirement is to get the first and last name in the list stored in separate String.Any suggestions?

```
    for (MyDTO result : results) {
        System.out.println("countName :" + result.getCountName());//returns 20 names
        System.out.println("Spread Percent :" + result.getSpreadPercent());
        System.out.println("Addr :" + result.getAddr());
    }
```

output:

```
ASD
xxx
Joh
Joe
xyz
```

I want the output as:

```
first Name: ASD
Last Name : xyz
```

Comment: How is that your ouptut? Where did the `countName` go? What about `Spread Percent` and `Addr`? What does your `MyDTO` look like? Which properties represent the first and last name? When you made the minimal effort to look up how to get first and last elements in a list, what did you find and what didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
MyDTO firstresult = results.get(0);//first value
MyDTO lastresult = results.get(results.size() - 1);//last value
```

This can return the same value if your list contain only one element.

**Note**

before you use this, you have to check if the list is not empty else you will get an exception.

```
MyDTO firstresult = null;
MyDTO lastresult  = null;
if (!results.isEmpty()) {
    firstresult = results.get(0);//first value
    lastresult = results.get(results.size() - 1);//last value
}
```

---

> Please see my updated code in post above.In the list i have many
>   properties like countName,SpreadPercent,Addr. I want to get only first
>   and last element value of countNam

With the same solution you can just use :

```
results.get(0).getCountName();
results.get(results.size() - 1).getAddr();
```

Comment: Please see my updated code in post above.In the list i have many properties like countName,SpreadPercent,Addr. I want to get only first and last element value of countName.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the indexes to access the elements:

```
System.out.println("First Name :" + results.get(0). getCountName());

System.out.println("Last Name :" + results.get(results.size()-1).getCountName());
```

---

***Edit*** :: Based on the

```
System.out.println("countName :" + result.getCountName());//returns 20 names
```

Seems like the `getCountName` returns a `List` further. To print just the firstName and lastName for this list, you can simply reuse the above code with indexing on the inner list as:

```
System.out.println("First Name :" + results.getCountName().get(0));

System.out.println("Last Name :" + reslts.getCountName().get(reslts.getCountName().size()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get any element of a list by the index, just be aware to move the index between 0 and `size - 1`

```
List<MyDTO> myList = ...
//the 1st element is
MyDTO fisrt = myList.get(0);
```

but since that is a list, you can too use a linkedList and use the methods get first and get last

```
List<MyDTO> x = new LinkedList<>();

MyDTO first = ((LinkedList<MyDTO>) x).getLast();
MyDTO last = ((LinkedList<MyDTO>) x).getFirst();
```